# How to repaint another image from the ending coordinates of first image?

Tags: java

I am just trying to make a simple aquarium type application. The fish moves from left to right. (the mouth of fish is faced towards right). When it reaches the end of the JFrame, it returns back. What I wanted is that it must face towards left when it returns.(goes back) So, I have decided to paint with a new image when the fish reaches at the specific coordinate. How to do it? Please.
image 1 = fish of image whose mouth is right faced
image 2 = fish of image whose mouth is left faced

```
package aquarium;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.Timer;


public class Aquarium extends JPanel implements ActionListener{
    Random r = new Random();
    Timer t = new Timer(5, this);
    int x = 0, y= 30;
    int velX = 1 ,velY =1;
    ImageIcon image  = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("../res/aquarium.gif"));
    ImageIcon image1 = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("../res/smallFish.gif"));
    ImageIcon image2 = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("../res/new.gif"));
    int numberFish = 12;
    Aquarium() {

    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        image.paintIcon(this, g, 0, 0);
        image1.paintIcon(this, g, x, y);
        t.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        Graphics g = null;
        if(x<0 || x>465) {
            velX = -velX; 
        }
    x += velX;
    repaint();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Aquarium a = new Aquarium();

        JFrame f = new JFrame();

        f.setTitle("The Aquarium");
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.setVisible(true);
        f.setResizable(false);
        f.setBounds(500,200,500,300); //left,top,width,height 
        f.add(a);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `velX` to check which fish it is and draw it:

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    super.paintComponent(g);

    image.paintIcon(this, g, 0, 0);
    if (velX > 0) { // moving right
        image1.paintIcon(this, g, x, y);
    } else { // moving left
        image2.paintIcon(this, g, x, y);

    }
    t.start();
}
```

Comment: Worked like a boss :D

Comment: Could you please tell me how can i float that fish?
Iknow I have to use random coordinates but how to implement

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by "float"?

Comment: I was going to say how to make that fish looks like it is swimming

Comment: Well, I'm not an expert on fish movement, but you could change the `velX` and `velY` every 5 seconds or so to a random value, for example `(int)(Math.random() * 10) - 5`